# Apache CXF ContainerRequestFilter with RSA and DS

Tags: osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, declarative-services

I'm migrating CXF REST endpoints from blueprint to Declarative Services that runs on Apache Karaf. I use Aries RSA and DOSGI. In the old code ContainerRequestFilter is used (specified in blueprint), but I am not sure how it can be used with DS? From [0] I can see that javax.servlet.Filter can be registered and I wonder what is the right approach. Is it possible to register ContainerRequestFilter by using DS annotations?

[0] http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using the JAX-RS Whiteboard from OSGi R7. [Registering a JAX-RS extension](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.jaxrs.html#service.jaxrs.extension.services) is as simple as making it an OSGi service providing the relevant service interface(s) - in this case `ContainerRequestFilter` and adding the service property "osgi.jaxrs.extension=true".

By also using R7 features from Declarative Services and bnd 4.0.0 this service property can be applied to Declarative Services components using the new ComponentPropertyType meta-annotations. A standard annotation `@JaxrsExtension` is part of the JAX-RS whiteboard specification.

For example:

```
@JaxrsResource
@Component
public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    // Implementation goes in here

}
```

The OSGi enRoute project provides other examples of using the JAX-RS whiteboard [in its examples](http://enroute.osgi.org/Examples/)